# Installed MariaDB over mysql, uninstalled, and reinstalled now getting errors

Tags: dpkg, mysql

Im currently getting dpkg errors and there are missing directorys for mysql-server

Tried looking up on google and nothing helped, I purged and everything.

Machine details:
Ubuntu 22.04

I ran the command `sudo apt install mysql-server` and got these errors during the end of the install:

```
update-alternatives: using /var/lib/mecab/dic/ipadic-utf8 to provide /var/lib/mecab/dic/debian (mecab-dictionary) in auto mode
Setting up libhtml-parser-perl:amd64 (3.76-1build2) ...
Setting up libhttp-message-perl (6.36-1) ...
Setting up mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.34-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-8.0.postinst: line 202: /usr/share/mysql-common/configure-symlinks: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-8.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Setting up libcgi-pm-perl (4.54-1) ...
Setting up libhtml-template-perl (2.97-1.1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-8.0; however:
  Package mysql-server-8.0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libcgi-fast-perl (1:2.15-1) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-8.0
 mysql-server
needrestart is being skipped since dpkg has failed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

When running `sudo mysql`:  ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) and the socket file is missing I checked.

I looked at posts with the same issues but no answers were found.

Comment: As it says, `mysql-server is not configured yet`. Do `sudo dpkg --configure -a`.

Comment: @Jos I ran the command, no errors, reran install command and get the same error

Comment: @Jos I seem to be missing multiple files, like its not doing a complete install, any ideas?

Comment: Strange. You could try to install `mysql-common` first. That is the package that provides the missing `/usr/share/mysql-common/configure-symlinks` script.